# How to reduce the image size without losing quality in PHP

Tags: php, image, performance, compression, google-pagespeed

I am trying to develop an image-based web site. I am really confused about the best image type for faster page loading speeds and best compression practices. Please advise me on the best way to compress image sizes.

Comment: Jpeg, gif and png images are already compressed.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd go for `jpeg`. Read [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/283366/reducing-an-image-size-without-losing-its-quality) regarding image size reduction and after deciding on the technique, use [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 119):

If you are looking to reduce the size using coding itself, you can follow this code in php.

```
<?php 
function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {

    $info = getimagesize($source);

    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

    return $destination;
}

$source_img = 'source.jpg';
$destination_img = 'destination .jpg';

$d = compress($source_img, $destination_img, 90);
?>
```

---

```
$d = compress($source_img, $destination_img, 90);
```

This is just a php function that passes the source image ( i.e., `$source_img` ), destination image ( `$destination_img` ) and quality for the image that will take to compress ( i.e., 90 ).

```
$info = getimagesize($source);
```

The `getimagesize()` function is used to find the size of any given image file and return the dimensions along with the file type.

Comment: this function convert the source images to JPEG, ignore the gif animations and png transparency

Comment: to overcome png transparency issue mentioned by @nikmauro, i used the
imagepng instead of  imagejpeg. using the imagejpeg for jpg files, ofcourse just modifying if statement to use appropriate function.

however to save transparency i also had to add (before output/save) :

    imagealphablending($image, false);
    imagesavealpha($image, true);

I also had to devide the $quality by 10 to work as imagepng does not go from 0 - 100 but rather 0 - 9

Comment: Good one there. But one thing that bothers me is why 90 for the compression? Is there a min value which when passed, the image is going to loose its "originality"?

Comment: I'm not sure why but the image gets rotated when I use this code, how would I prevent this from happening. It always seems to be rotated 90 degrees anti clockwise.

Comment: sorted, I had to read the exif data from the original image and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Great! This is working but I'm getting 1 issue with it. While I'm uploading image thru the mobile camera then it sometimes rotates that image 90 degrees.
What to do about that??

Answer (score 10):

You can resize and then use imagejpeg()

Don't pass 100 as the quality for imagejpeg() - anything over 90 is generally overkill and just gets you a bigger JPEG. For a thumbnail, try 75 and work downwards until the quality/size tradeoff is acceptable.

```
imagejpeg($tn, $save, 75);
```

Comment: how to move the resized image to particular folder?

Answer (score 5):

well I think I have something interesting for you... https://github.com/whizzzkid/phpimageresize. I wrote it for the exact same purpose. Highly customizable, and does it in a great way.