# How big are the images that Instagram uses to populate its feed?

Tags: android, performance, instagram, bandwidth

I have a use case for an Android app where I need to populate something like Instagram's feed with quite a lot of images. The problem is that I think it might take a lot of bandwidth. I was wondering if anyone knows how Instagram, for example, reduces the size of the images that they use for the feed, as they surely keep the proper quality images in their storage.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram images are mostly of 640 x 640 dimensions and are less then 100 kbs in size which reduces bandwidth while quality is not compromise very much. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19404938/1432690) on how to reduce image size with php.