# How to automatically compress photos/videos for website when uploaded?

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, optimization

I am working on a website in which I give users the possibility to upload pictures and videos, how would I automatically compress those videos/pictures server-side before storing them on my server/database. because I don't want abnormally large files to slow down my website, if I was uploading myself I could obviously resize and optimize myself, but is there a way I can do this automatically for my users?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the best PHP method to reduce the image size without losing quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418594/which-is-the-best-php-method-to-reduce-the-image-size-without-losing-quality)

Comment: There are a number of utilities out there that will do that for you. Unless you're really intent on trying to code that yourself, you should look in to whichever one suits your application needs best.

Answer (score -2):

Well, that is a wide question and answer depends on type of the files and algorithm you decide to select.

For images, you can simply use JPG and select desired percentage quality (the smaller, the better size, but worse looking resulting picture). Example: http://blog.clonesinfo.com/how-to-reduce-compress-image-file-size-uploading-using-php-code/

If you want more options or for example lossless quality, you definitely should look for some library or tool, look in this question for some more info: [Which is the best PHP method to reduce the image size without losing quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418594/which-is-the-best-php-method-to-reduce-the-image-size-without-losing-quality)

For videos, it gets a little more complicated, as making a video smaller requires re-encoding it, and also picking the right settings (the codec you usually pick will be the most compatible and efficient one – H.264, or something like VP9 from Google). Note that re-encoding requires significant amount of processing power on your server (might start to be an issue if videos are large and long). Video encoding is a very wide topic which I cannot cover here in 1 response, you can start with googling around how H.264 works.

For video encoding you're also going to need a tool, probably the best choice will be ffmpeg/avconv, plus some PHP library to make it easier to use.