# massive file size with pictures

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I'm using opentbs to get an organization chart with photographs.

People register pictures with no size limit. I'd like to know if it exists a tag that compresses the pictures before editing.
I actually use

```
[XXXX;ope=changepic;tagpos=inside;adjust]
```

It makes pictures look small, but they weight the same. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately OpenTBS does not have a feature for reducing picture size because modifying a picture is a big task and it is far from the goal of a Template Engine. OpenTBS actually does not change the picture inserted in the document, event if the size showed by the document is not the same as the inner picture.

Hopefully they are other PHP tools that you can use in order to reduce pictures before to merge them with OpenTBS.

See for example :

- [Which is the best PHP method to reduce the image size without losing quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418594/which-is-the-best-php-method-to-reduce-the-image-size-without-losing-quality)
- [How to Compress Image Size Without Losing Quality in
  PHP](https://dev.to/niick007/how-to-compress-image-size-without-losing-quality-in-php-4d2h)

Since the compressed pictures are merged, you can deleted them in the same script.

Comment: thank you, I'll tell that to the PHP coding engineer I work with